# Preciso que o Atributo de um Dataset HDF5 seja uma string

Tags: c#, string, atributos, variáveis, hdf5

Boa tarde, estou tentando criar alguns atributos para meus datasets, consegui criar os atributos mas na hora de setar seus valores (strings) nao estou conseguindo, já tentei de diversas formas diferentes, e atualmente a string que aparece parece estar bugada ou em outro formato... O código que estou usando é o abaixo:

Consegui Criar os Atributos "Eng. Unit" e "Atrib2", porém nao consigo setar seus valores como "Temperatua" e "Teste", respectivamente

```
        foreach (BasicVariable bv in pf.basicVariableList.bvList)
        {               
            H5DataSetId dataSetId = H5D.create(bvGroupId, bv.bvTag, typeId, spaceId);
            bv.atribList.Add(new Atribbs("Eng. Unit", "Temperatura"));
            bv.atribList.Add(new Atribbs("Atrib2", "Teste"));
            foreach(Atribbs a in bv.atribList )
            {


                H5DataTypeId auxDT = H5T.copy(H5T.H5Type.C_S1);
                H5T.setSize(auxDT, H5T.getSize(H5T.H5Type.C_S1));
                const int auxData = 2;
                long[] auxDim = new long[1];
                auxDim[0] = 1;
                H5DataSpaceId auxDS = H5S.create_simple(1, auxDim);


                var attr_id = H5A.create(dataSetId, a.attName, auxDT, auxDS);
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(a.valueStr);
                var atrData = new string[] { Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes)};
                H5A.write<string>(attr_id, auxDT, new H5Array<string>(atrData));

                H5A.close(attr_id);
            }
            H5D.close(dataSetId);
        }
        H5F.close(fileId);
```

Na tela do HDF View eles aparecem assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]